# Accessing parallel port in Java?

Tags: java, port

How do you access a parallel port in Java? I tried many libraries such as parport and javax.comm but none have worked.

Can anyone recommend a library with parallel port control?

I am trying to turn on a LED and I have to use Java and Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

Because the significance of parallel ports is dropping, you have to resort to old libraries in order to work with them.

It is fairly simple to work with the parallel port in Java on WinXP. You have two basic options:

1. [comm.jar](http://www.cs.uml.edu/~fredm/courses/91.305/software/JDK118-javaxcomm.zip) and
2. [RxTx](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/rxtx/rxtx/2.1.7/rxtx-2.1.7.jar)

You will have to read the installation instructions carefully, since it is not sufficient to just install the jar files. There are also a few .dll files (win32com.dll) you will need to place to the appropriate directories in order to make things work.

Check also [Oracle Java Communications 3.0 API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html)...